# clone all element and content inside div and display it into another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Get all elements inside a particular div and display the the same to other div.
the content inside  is dynamic .
I want to clone all the elements  inside  
    ie

```
<div id="div_preview"> 
  <br>
  2 php Developer ?<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_0" value="a">
  a
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_1" value="b">
  b
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_2" value="c">
  c 
  </div>

from <div id="div_preview">  and display it to <div id='other_div'></div>
```

so that o/p

```
 <br>
      2 php Developer ?<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk_0" value="a">
      a
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk_1" value="b">
      b
      <input type="checkbox" name="chk_2" value="c">
      c
```

Comment: `jQuery.clone().appendTo(TARGET_ELEMENT)`

Comment: Right, and how's that working out?

Comment: but it will also clone the div ' div_preview'  i want content inside id='div_preview'

Comment: then do something like:

var cloned_children = $("#div_preview").clildren().clone();
$("#other_div").append(cloned_children);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('other_div').innerHTML = document.getElementById('div_preview').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Displays in alert:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        alert($('#div_preview').html());    

    });
```

Comment: or you can simply use this-


$('#targetDiv').html($('#div_preview').html);

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function{
var result=$('#div_preview').html();
$("other_div").html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `contents` for that - just clone the contents and then add the cloned elements to the new container.

Here is an example:

```js
$('#div_preview').contents().clone().appendTo('#div_container')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_preview"> 
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_0" value="a">
  a
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_1" value="b">
  b
  <input type="checkbox" name="chk_2" value="c">
  c 
</div>
<br />

<div id="div_container"></div>
```